# How do I pass data from a database from one controller to another controller that has its own database in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two controllers:

AaController have a view named Index and a database context that we can call for dbContextAa

RrController also has its own database, which we can call for dbContextRr and an action method GetData ()

What I wonder is; how do I do if I want to take the data from the method GetData () and display it in the index view.

Previously, I tested with Temp Data and Sessions without any result. I had no value at all in the view from RrDatabase.
If I understand it right, I have to use Dependency Injections.

So here I have created dependency injection (not sure if it is correct)

AaController:

```
public class AaController : Controller
{
    private RrController rc;

    public AaController(RrController rr, AaContext aaContext)
    {
        rc = rr;
        _aaContext = aaContext;
    }

public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var dataFromRr= rs.GetData();

        ViewBag.rrData = dataFromRr;

        return View();
    }
```

RrController:

```
public class RrController : Controller
{
    private readonly RrContext _rrContext;

    public RrController(RrContext rrContext)
    {
        _rrContext = rrContext;
    }

public IActionResult GetData()
    {
        var data = _rrContext.RrData.Count(x => x.Pid == x.Pid);


        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Aa", data );
    }
```

Instead of the value of the view I get Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `GetData` method returns an `IActionResult` type response(specifically MVC action result, `RedirectResult`).

Ideally what you should be doing is, extract the code which gives you the relevant data to a method in a separate class, which you can use in multiple places as needed (ControllerA and ControllerR).

Let's create an interface and a class to implement it.

```
public interface IRService
{
   int GetRDataCount(int pId);
}

public class RService : IRService
{
   private RrContext _rrContext;     
   public RService (RrContext rrContext)
   {
      this._rrContext=rrContext;
   }  
   public int GetRDataCount(int pId)
   {
     return _rrContext.RrData.Count(x => x.Pid == pId);
   }
}
```

You can inject `IRService` implementation to your controllers and call the `GetRDataCount` method to get the int value.

```
public class AaController : Controller
{
    private IRService rService;

    public AaController(IRService rService)
    {
        this.rService=rService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        int countVal = this.rService.GetRDataCount(234); // pass actual PId

        ViewBag.rrData = countVal;

        return View();
    }    
}
```

Make sure to add the `IRservice`  to `RService` dependency mapping in your Startup class.

Now wherever you want to get the RData count for a specific pId, you can inject an `IRservice` implementation and use it (Do it in your `RController` as well)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different approaches depending on the structure of your projects and how (and if) they can communicate with one another.

> What I wonder is; how do I do if I want to take the data from the
>   method GetData () and display it in the index view.

Your `GetData()` method is actually attempting to return a View on it's own, however it looks like what you want to do is actually just return the data (i.e. the count) and pass that to your other action:

```
public int GetData()
{
    var data = _rrContext.RrData.Count(x => x.Pid == x.Pid);
    // This will pass a parameter that contains your count
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Aa", new { count = data });
}
```

You need to actually pass your data to the View as a "model". This can easy be done by simply decorating your View with the type of data that you are going to be passing in:

```
public IActionResult Index(int count)
{
    // The count parameter will have the current result of your previous call in it
    return View(count);
}
```

Then you would just need to tell your actual View how you wanted to present the data (i.e. what type it was) via the `@model` directive at the top of the view:

```
@model int

There were @Model records found.
```

**Consider A Service**

A better implementation would be to consider using a service that decouples your logic from any one specific controller. This would allow you to simply instantiate the service and call it from wherever it was needed as [Shyju's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42740463/557445) indicates.